# makefile patsubst module/src/class.cpp to build/module/class.o

Tags: makefile, wildcard

I am write makefile for my project, ant the structure is

```
.
├── file
│   ├── include
│   │   └── FileIO.hpp
│   └── src
│       └── FileIO.cpp
├── main
├── main.cpp
├── makefile
├── ui
│   ├── include
│   │   ├── KeyValues.hpp
│   │   ├── MAP.hpp
│   │   ├── NotifyMessageVo.hpp
│   │   ├── Str2MAP.hpp
│   │   └── Value.hpp
│   ├── makefile
│   └── src
│       └── Str2MAP.cpp
```

so I want to use `patsubst` to generate objs files from *.cpp from each module. For example, I want to generate build/file/FileIO.o from file/src/FileIO.cpp. I just don't know how to generate it automatically by makefile.

Comment: And `ui/src/foo.cpp` => `build/ui/foo.o`?

Comment: @Beta yes, I choose to `OBJ := $(patsubst %.cpp, $(BUILD_ROOT)/%.o, $(SRC))`
`OBJ := $(foreach o, $(OBJ), $(subst /src/,, $(o)))`, meanwhile `$(BUILD_ROOT)=build`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OBJ := $(patsubst %.cpp,build/%.o,$(SRC))
OBJ := $(subst /src/,/,$(OBJ))
```

Or as one line:

```
OBJ := $(patsubst %.cpp,build/%.o,$(subst /src/,/,$(SRC)))
```